# startRecordingToOutputFileURL no active/enabled connections ios

Tags: ios, camera, avcapturesession

I want to record a short clip (30 sec) that should be automatically stopped after 30 sec. I started the camera using `AVCAPTURESESSION`  and now I want to start video recording that should be automatically.

**Here's my code:**

```
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
[session addInput:input];

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];
newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:newCaptureVideoPreviewLayer];

[session startRunning];
```

How do I record video of 30 sec.

**My Try:**

```
NSString *documentsDirPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
NSURL *documentsDirUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:documentsDirPath isDirectory:YES];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"out.mp4" relativeToURL:documentsDirUrl];
[self.movieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:url recordingDelegate:self];



- (AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *)movieFileOutput {
    AVCaptureMovieFileOutput *_movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
    if (!_movieFileOutput) {
        _movieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];

        Float64 TotalSeconds = 30;          //Total seconds
        int32_t preferredTimeScale = 30;    //Frames per second
        CMTime maxDuration = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(TotalSeconds, preferredTimeScale);
        _movieFileOutput.maxRecordedDuration = maxDuration;
        _movieFileOutput.minFreeDiskSpaceLimit = 1024 * 1024;
    }

    return _movieFileOutput;
}
```

But it gives me error, `[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:recordingDelegate:] - no active/enabled connections.'`

How can I record a video clip of 30 sec.

Answer (score 0):

I find the reason of this error. check your session's "setSessionPreset" setting, photo's resolution setting is different from video, for iPhone5, video resolution of the back camera is 1920*1080, the front camere is 1280*720, and photo's max resolution is 3264*2488, so if you set error resolution to video, the connect will not be actived.